# Run jps on command promt

Tags: java, python, hadoop, cmd, environment-variables

I installed Hadoop and tried to run it. The terminal shows that everything has been started but when I run jps command it shows :

```
'jps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I set    **JAVA_HOME**= **C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_261** and **path** = **C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin**   and  **C:\Program~1\Java\jre1.8.0_261\legal\jdk**  in enviroment, but when I type jps in command prompt it shows : Not recognized as an internal or external command.
I don't know what can I do, Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `jps` executable is no present in the bin directory that you've specified in system environment variable. It should be inside `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin` if you have `jdk1.8.0_26` installed in your system in the location `C:\Program Files`. Try specifying the `JAVA_HOME` like this:

1. Go to `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`.
2. Add a new path variable called `JAVA_HOME`:
   `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261`
3. Select `Path` from `System Variables` and click `Edit`.
4. Remove the existing Java path and add the new path as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
5. Now, open command window, type `jps` and hit `ENTER`.

> Note: You can download JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html#license-lightbox)

Comment: I set variable and path like this you said but it doesn't work.  in %JAVA_HOME%\bin, I haven't jps file. should I have a jps file in the bin or not?

Comment: You should have a jps executable file inside the bin. You want to reinstall JDK from the above link and follow the steps?

Comment: I reinstalled it again and now I have jps.exe in the bin and I set variable and path, but when I type jps in command prompt, it's showing the same error = 'jps' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I don't know what can I do? it's so confusing.

Comment: You have to open a new command prompt after setting the path in environment variable.

Comment: I add the image above, I opened a new command prompt.

Comment: What do you see when you type javac -version from command prompt?

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program, or batch file. I see this

Comment: This makes more sense, i.e, the PATH that you've set in Environment variable is wrong. Check the value of environment Path, JAVA_HOME variables and make sure the value of JAVA_HOME is the actual JDK installed directory.

Comment: I don't know what is my problem, I set all of the variables like this which you said, but it doesn't work, unfourtunately. I'm started using google. collab. thanks, Sarath for everything.